# iTunes 12.5 - Add photo of artist / edit rainbow microphone thumbnail

Tags: itunes

In the "Artist" view of iTunes 12.5, is it possible to make a photo of the artist (or at least one of the album covers) appear in place of the rainbow microphone?

[image]

**Update** (2017)

It appears that with 12.5.5.5 (possibly earlier, but I didn't notice), Artists that are known to Apple now have their photos set correctly:

[image]

There still doesn't appear to be a way to manually set or override this image though.

Comment: It's supposed to. I have no idea how to force it to do so, though. (I'd think Adele would have one at least.)

Comment: This is music from CD that I ripped myself as ALAC -- wonder if that's the reason?

Comment: Yeah that's entirely possible. Looking through my library now, it does seem as though the only ones that have photos there are ones where I have at least one track purchased from the iTMS (even if there are other, non-iTMS tracks for that artist as well).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution, but I believe I've discovered the root cause of the issue.

In the iTunes store, each artist has a biography page. Some artists have a band image, others do not. For every artist in my library that has an image, it is the same image on their iTunes bio. For every microphone, the artists bio is text only.

[image: My artist Library]
[image: Dillinger Escape Plan]
[image: Faith No More]
[image: Henry Rollins]
[image: Jasta]

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the Artist picture (when iTunes actually posts it) comes from the artist's bio, but that doesn't mean it will show up.  Take a look at these two photos.  The one on the left side shows the microphone where Alice Cooper's photo should be.  The one on the right shows Alice Cooper's bio page where there IS a photo in place.

It would be easier to look the other way if there was consistency.   I'd just chalk it up as being a work in progress.  That's just not the case.  It's a bug that Apple has just ignored since the release of 12.5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, missing artist images do not depend on the source of the music. Even if you bought it from Apple, you may get the ugly microphone images!

Comment: Hi Ulli, once you've spent some time around the site, you'll be able to reply to comments... We ask that the "Answer" section be reserved only for answers to the posted question, i.e. "Can I set the Artist thumbnails manually?"

Comment: Perfectly qualifies as an answer to what turned out to be the question. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting.  While iTunes and iOS iphone have lots of microphones for my artists, I recently downloaded Apple Music for my Android Note 9.  In that version, the vast majority of my artists show either a photo or it shows the album cover from one of the albums (something it used to show as a default prior to 12.5).  Why would Apple Music on Android show something not even seen in iTunes or iOS?!?

See below, iTunes, iOS and then Android Apple Music

[image: MacOS/iTunes]
[image: iPhone/iOS]
[image: Android Apple Music]